# Facebook Query Language using python

Tags: python, facebook-fql

i used the following query in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=

```
SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = "100001741044617";
```

and i got the right output.

i tried using the same query via python and extract the output i am getting a problem. 
i am posting the python code and the output

CODE:

```
import urllib
query = "SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = \"100001741044617\""
print(query)
query = urllib.quote(query)
print(query)
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" +query

data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print(data)
```

OUTPUT

```
[root@IN-AIR-BIMAPP106 ~]# python /opt/fql.py 
SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = "100001741044617"
SELECT%20aid%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%20%22100001741044617%22
{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}
```

I have already generated the required access token user_photoes.
Kindly let me know what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The access token needs to be included in your query.  For example, to get all your friends:

```
query = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()"
params = urllib.urlencode({'q': query, 'access_token': YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN})
print params

'q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+%3D+me%28%29&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?" + params
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print(data)

'{"data":[{"uid2":"#######"},{"uid2":"#######"},{"uid2":"#######"}, ...
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. i tried executing it, its not able to recognize the accesstoken. i tries it out as number and also as a string. but aint working.

Comment: how did you generate the access token? try generating one using the [access token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) and check that works for you, at least using the example above.  it should identify whether the problem is with your token generation.  note that if you are using a bad token, the response will tell you so explicitly (can't remember exact wording) - if the response is simply empty then it's your fql query that's the problem.  let me know if you need more help.